# Outputting each array item into line in textbox

Tags: vba, ms-access

Is there a function to cleanly output each array item as a new line in a text box? Right now my current code adds an extra vbNewLine (line break) at the end that I have to remove:

```
For Each ArrayItem In Array
    OutputText = OutputText & ArrayItem & vbNewLine
Next ArrayItem

Me.MyTextBox = Left(OutputText, Len(OutputText) - 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than looping the array, use the VBA function `Join`:

```
Me.MyTextBox=Join(Array,vbNewLine)
```

Regards,